# Framer motion mobile lag/freezes

Tags: animation, next.js, styled-components, motion, framer-motion

I am new to framer-motion. I built an application with framer and Next.js. But the issue is it's working fine on Pc but It's freezing at a point on the mobile. I have read so many documents and from that, I am guessing it's an Fps issue. But not sure.

Here is the website link: https://haveraw-app.vercel.app/

Please help me with that. How can I fix this issue? Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off power saving mode on your mobile device

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).